# How to change browser time zone in react JS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone

I have a requirement in which I have to change the time of the whole application according to an env variable. The whole application will work with the time zone specified in the file. For example, if the given time zone is America/New_York then regardless of the user's time zone the application should show EDT or EST date (If I do new Date().toLocaleString() then it should be America New York local time). Tech stack I am using Next JS v.13.

I tried adding next-intl and pass timeZone prop but no luck. Ultimately, I have configured server time & changed schema from Date to String and store the date in string in the database without time zone, and then utilized that string and converted that in the front end. But this causes lot of other issues. I am in search of an optimal solution.

Comment: You can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to convert every time stamp in your application to the desired time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @HeikoTheißen but as I told, I have already done that but with a moment (pretty much the same stuff you commented). The problem is node modules using JavaScript Date are hard to deal with (For example Calendar component). I want the browser time zone to be changed or at least the toLocalString() function should return American time to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `toLocaleString` method of the `Date` object so that it uses `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```js
Date.prototype.toLocaleString = function(date) {
  return Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York",
    dateStyle: "medium",
    timeStyle: "medium"
  }).format(date);
};
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
```